# Extra Column in Select Query while Using .Include () EF CORE which does not Exist in SQL Table neither in entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I'm using EF Core and while initializing the project, I'm using this code to load the initial data which I need in all applications. But I'm getting an error

> "XXX" column does not exist in SQL

When I checked with SQL Server profiler, there is an extra column in the `Select` query "XXX" which doesn't exist in the table:

```
var settings = _context.Settings
                       .Include(x => x.DefaultLanguage)
                       .Include(x => x.NewMembersStartingRoles);
```

Comment: May I ask for your code?
Your mapper, context, models

Comment: So the message is correct. That means that one of your models (`DefaultLanguage` or `NewMembersStartingRoles`) contains a field that should be removed from the model.